# Can I do sculpting after i baked it

Tags: sculpting, texture-baking, baking, sculpt, sculpt-mode

I did bake my sculpture after coloring and texturing and then I found out that there is something on my sculpture and I need to fix it with sculpting tools. Is it somehow possible to do it? Or I have to open not baked last version and start over? Thanks for answers.

Comment: I think sculpting will destroy the UV data for the affected faces (perhaps depending on what tool you use).  You'd at least have to unwrap and bake your textures again.

Comment: I was afraid of this answer, I noticed that mistake on my sculpture later. But I think I’ll need moving and maybe smoothing tool

Comment: You can sculpt, but without Dyntopo that generates extra vertices.

Comment: Thank you for answers, I appreciate this